# $\cap$-stable subset of a Dynkin system implies that its $\sigma$-algebra is contained in the Dynkin system?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading Schilling's proof of the result that $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(X,\mathscr A,\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathscr B,\nu)$ admit a (unique) product measure $\mu\times\nu$ with certain properties. At some point in the proof, they construct a Dynkin systems $\mathscr D_n$, and note that $\mathscr A\times\mathscr B\subset\mathscr D_n$ is $\cap$-closed (note that $\mathscr D_n$ itself is not necessarily $\cap$-closed). They conclude then that
$$
\sigma(\mathscr A\times\mathscr B)\subset\mathscr D_n.
$$
Now, clearly, $\sigma(\mathscr A\times\mathscr B)\subset\sigma(\mathscr D_n)$, and for $\cap$-stable Dynkin systems, we know that they are $\sigma$-algebras. However, I don't know how to show the inclusion $\sigma(\mathscr A\times\mathscr B)\subset\mathscr D_n$. Before diving into Dynkin systems again (rereading proofs and all), I was wondering if there maybe just is a simple argument why this inclusion holds? (since Schilling doesn't elaborate on it)

Comment: How is $\mathscr{D}$ constructed? without knowing that noone could answer this.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I wondered first if the result would hold without any further knowledge of $\mathscr D$. I've added now how it's constructed.

Comment: I removed the construction again, because it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is simple indeed (I had overlooked Theorem 5.5 in Schilling; they even refer to this theorem, but I thought they were referring to Lemma 5.4 for some reason):

By Theorem 5.5, we have $\delta(\mathscr A\times\mathscr B)=\sigma(\mathscr A\times\mathscr B)$, since $\mathscr A\times\mathscr B$ is stable under finite intersections. Since $\mathscr A\times\mathscr B\subset\mathscr D$, we have that $\delta(\mathscr A\times\mathscr B)\subset\mathscr\delta (\mathscr D)=\mathscr D$ (by Prop. 5.3), hence the inclusion I wanted to show holds.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable argument to me.